# sklearn VotingClassifier with RandomizedSearchCV gives pickle error

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I'm trying to get randomized hyperparameter search to work with the voting classifier from sklearn by adapting the [example given in the sklearn documentation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/ensemble.html#using-the-votingclassifier-with-gridsearchcv).

I've seen [this minimal working example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35534452/4138853), but it breaks in many ways using my version of sklearn.

Here is a stripped-down example:

```py
import numpy as np
from sklearn import __version__ as skv
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier as RFClassi
from sklearn.ensemble import HistGradientBoostingClassifier as HGBClassi
from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeClassifier as DTClassi
from sklearn.model_selection import RandomizedSearchCV
from sklearn.ensemble import VotingClassifier
from sklearn.datasets import load_iris

print(f"sklearn version: {skv}")

df_X, target = load_iris(return_X_y=True, as_frame=True)
ensemble = ['rf','dtree','hgb']
hy_pa_grid = {
    'hgb': dict(learning_rate = list(np.linspace(0.01,0.5,10).round(3))),
    'rf':dict(criterion = ['gini', 'entropy']),
    'dtree':dict(criterion = ['gini', 'entropy']),
}
clfs = {'hgb' : HGBClassi(), 'rf': RFClassi(), 'dtree' : DTClassi()}
vc = VotingClassifier(estimators = clfs.items(), voting = 'soft')
params = {
    f"{c}__{p}" : hy_pa_grid[c][p]
    for c in ensemble
    for p in hy_pa_grid[c].keys()
}
print("\n".join(map(str,params.items())))
clf = RandomizedSearchCV(estimator = vc, param_distributions = params)
clf.fit(df_X,target)
```

The output I get is this:

```
sklearn version: 1.1.3
{'rf__criterion': ['gini', 'entropy'], 'dtree__criterion': ['gini', 'entropy'], 'hgb__learning_rate': [0.01, 0.064, 0.119, 0.173, 0.228, 0.282, 0.337, 0.391, 0.446, 0.5]}
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "vc.py", line 34, in <module>
    clf.fit(df_X,target)                
  File "/home/USER/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sklearn/model_selection/_search.py", line 789, in fit
    base_estimator = clone(self.estimator)
  File "/home/USER/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sklearn/base.py", line 87, in clone
    new_object_params[name] = clone(param, safe=False)
  File "/home/USER/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sklearn/base.py", line 68, in clone
    return copy.deepcopy(estimator)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/copy.py", line 161, in deepcopy
    rv = reductor(4)
TypeError: cannot pickle 'dict_items' object
```

Any ideas for getting round this?  I also tried doing it with GridSearchCV, as in the example, but I get the same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oops, it turns out the problem was in

```py
estimators = clfs.items()
```

All was well once I wrapped it in `tuple()` to be an actual tuple rather than a generator.